# Adding buttons dynamically to linearView

Tags: java, android, button, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to write an application that’s adding buttons dynamically.
The application receives an image from the server and adding a button (no functionality for now).

The main activity is holding linear layout which will contain the buttons and a surface view that would receive the images and would create the buttons in the main activity.

The problem is that after the first image has been received the application crash while trying to add a new button to the view.

This is the surface view code:

```
public void run() {
        while ( isRunning){
            if ( !ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }

            Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas(); // Semafor for the canvas
            canvas.drawRGB(20,20,80);

            if (getNumOfBoards() > 0){
                canvas.drawBitmap(getCurrentBoard(), 0, 0, null);
            }

            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
```

This is the Main Activity add button code

```
public void addButtons(int numOfButton) {
                // create patameter
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );

                // create new button
                Button newbutton = new Button(this);

                // set background color
                newbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                // set width and height
                newbutton.setWidth(30);
                newbutton.setHeight(20);

                // set position
                newbutton.setY((float)numOfButton*20);
                newbutton.setX(0);

                // set text
                newbutton.setText("new button");

                // add button to the layout
                buttons.addView(newbutton,p);// **the application crash here**
    }
```

Comment: what is the error message (LogCat) from the crash?

Comment: can you give a try with this, am not sure.   replace this `buttons.addView(newbutton,p);` with  `p.addView(newbutton);`

Comment: What is "buttons"? Did you initialize it in onCreate?

Comment: @Taras, user has mentioned that the app crashes, which means, it's not compile time error, It's run time error, obviously, he has initialized :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick responds,
1.The error message from the logcat is mostly:"   android.view.ViewGroups.addView(viewGroups.java:1234)" .
2.I've tried to change buttons.addView(newbutton,p); withp.addView(newbutton); - it didn't fixed it… : (
3.Buttons initialized in the constractor to a linearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way android handles the Activities, the constructor `onCreate` is not guaranteed to have been called every time the `addButtons` method is executed 
(See the [`Activity Lifecycle Section`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) at developer.android.com)

You had better find the `buttons` LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout buttons = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutButtons);
```

in `addButtons` and add the new button.